# How to resolve function and call other function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two functions and I want to call one function after other only first function is resolved successfully.

```
$scope.createNewWorkModule = function (data, selectedUser) {

        $scope.workOrderInfo = $localStorage.workOrderInfo;

        $scope.createNewWorkOrder($scope.workOrderInfo).then(function (response) {

            $scope.workOrderId = $localStorage.workOrderId;

            var newWM = {
                name: data.name,
            };

            $scope.myPromise = operationsFactory.createWorkModule(angular.toJson(newWM)).success(function (response) {

                $rootScope.workModules = response.result;
                return $scope.workOrder;

            })
        });
    };

    $scope.createNewWorkOrder = function (data) {

        var newWD = {
            name: data.name,
            description: data.description,
            user_id: $cookies.userId
        };

        $scope.myPromise = operationsFactory.createWorkOrder(angular.toJson(newWD)).success(function (response) {

            $localStorage.workOrderId = response.result.id;

        })

        return $localStorage.workOrderId;
    };
```

I am trying to call `$scope.createNewWorkOrder` with `.then` but it is giving error that

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.createNewWorkModule (work-order-create-controller.js:36)
    at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12158)`.

How do I fix this?

Update:

Unable to update the view with data retrieved:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading font-bold">
        <span>List of Work Modules</span>
    </div>
    <ul ng-repeat="wm in workModules" style="list-style: none">
        <li>{{wm.name}}</li>
        <li>{{wm.description}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your asynchronous functions should always return the promises.
2. Make sure the `then` success functions always return the values needed by the next handler in the chain (and don't use the deprecated `.success` method as that doesn't chain correctly, always use `.then` but be aware of the slightly different parameter is gets from `$http` results).

Also try not to put things into `$scope` unless you really need them there, probably many of your functions can be just functions and the values could be local variables in the controller.

Note that once you are using `.then` you can issue a new call at the end of one success handler and process the result with another `.then` at the same level, no need to nest things further.

```
$scope.createNewWorkModule = createNewWorkModule; // Do you need both this
$scope.createNewWorkOrder = createNewWorkOrder; // and this?

function createNewWorkModule(data, selectedUser) {
    $scope.workOrderInfo = $localStorage.workOrderInfo;

    return createNewWorkOrder($scope.workOrderInfo)
    .then(function (workOrderId) {
        $scope.workOrderId = workOrderId;
        var newWM = {
            name: data.name,
        };

        return operationsFactory.createWorkModule(angular.toJson(newWM));
    })
    .then(function (response) {
            // here we have response from the createWorkModule call
            $rootScope.workModules = response.data.result;
            return $scope.workOrder;
    });
};

function createNewWorkOrder(data) {
    var newWD = {
        name: data.name,
        description: data.description,
        user_id: $cookies.userId
    };

    return operationsFactory.createWorkOrder(angular.toJson(newWD))
    .then(function (response) {
        var workOrderId = $localStorage.workOrderId = response.data.result.id;
        return workOrderId;
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Duncan. One problem is I am not able to update the view the model data(workModules) even though its in root scope

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error `then is not a function`, because the value returned is `undefined` as `$localStorage.workOrderId` is resolved async. Ideally you should return a promise.

```
return operationsFactory.createWorkOrder(angular.toJson(newWD)).success(function (response) {

       $localStorage.workOrderId = response.result.id;
       return $localStorage.workOrderId;

});
```

Comment: updated the question with error. I guess your answer still applies?

Comment: One problem is I am not able to update the view the model data(workModules) even though its in root scope. Updated the question. Please check once